# Static sidebar in a list view

Tags: filemaker

Is it possible to create a static sidebar on the left-hand-side of a list view in Filemaker?

I was hoping to have editable search criteria on the left and a list on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in list view, although you can achieve that UI with a portal. There are a lot of ways to populate the portal based on the search criteria - you can build a complex self-join relationship, use portal filtering (which is the easiest way, but will be slow for large numbers of records), or do either a scripted find in another window (slower but easy to program) or an SQL query (faster but requires a plugin and harder to program) and populate a global field with the IDs of the matching records and do a join based on that.